# How to change the text of the command to run an app in Linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, terminal, command

I use Arch. For example, in order to run Google Chrome in terminal you have to run the long command `google-chrome-stable`. How can I change this command to make it more concise (`chrome`, for example)? I run this browser often from the terminal because it's more convenient for web-development when you write some html/css code in text editor and run it using the browser to see how it works.
Thank you! And sorry for my English, it's not my first language.

Comment: Look up aliases in the documentation for bash or whatever shell you use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I've just added the line `alias chrome="google-chrome-stable"` to my `~/.bashrc` file and reboot the system.